# How do I change default session from plasma x11 to plasma wayland in OpenSUSE tumbleweed?

Tags: kde, opensuse, wayland, plasma5, sddm

I run latest OpenSUSE tumbleweed, KDE only. I wish to switch the default session from Plasma X11 to Plasma wayland. What should I do to achieve this?

The login manager I use comes from sddm. And I can indeed manually log in from the login manager to a wayland session.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I deleted the cross-post on Super User. Got the memo, and added details here.

Answer (score 0):

Without modifying any settings or configuration on my Tumbleweed install, SDDM seems to be remembering the last session that I used (which was Plasma on Wayland). This behavior may be what you're looking for!

Also this may be a non-issue soon, as KDE Plasma 6 will be Wayland by default. This means it likely will also eventually be the default KDE session provided by distributions such as Tumbleweed.

---

But, if neither of the above work and you *really* want to fix it before Plasma 6 launches, you can also try your hand at modifying the configuration file at `/etc/sddm.conf` (or `/etc/sddm.conf.d/kde-settings.conf` if you selected "*Apply KDE settings to SDDM*" in system settings). If mis-configured, this may break SDDM, so I would first suggest making a backup of your current configuration somewhere you remember, then copying over your changes as you experiment with settings. If all else fails, or you didn't take a backup beforehand, you can regenerate the default SDDM config again with `sddm --example-config > path to .conf file you modified above`.

The ultimate goal of updating the above config would be to display `/usr/share/wayland-sessions/plasmawayland.desktop` as the default selected option, which itself launches the plasma wayland session with `/usr/bin/startplasma-wayland`. To do this, a list of available settings for SDDM can be found in the SDDM GitHub page for the config file: https://github.com/sddm/sddm/blob/v0.20.0/data/man/sddm.conf.rst.in.